# Как сделать автоматическую прокрутку к нужному слову в тексте

Tags: javascript, angular2, прокрутка, textarea, angular5

Когда перехожу из поиска по нужному слову в textarea где есть большой текст, у меня уже есть первый индекс этого слова и последний индекс. С помощью этого делаю `setSelectionRange(firstIndex,lastIndex)` и `focus()`.

Но проблема в том, что автоматическая прокрутка к этому слову не работает и нужно вручную скроллить чтоб увидеть выделенное слово. Как это решить ?
[image: Результат поиска]
[image: Выделенное слово и полоса прокрутки]

```
  ngOnInit() {
    const subscription = this.pageService.subject.subscribe(
      r => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.textareaNovel.nativeElement.focus();
          const firstIndex = this.pageService.allIndex[this.pageService.indexOfOne];
          const lastIndex = firstIndex + this.pageService.inputSearchText.length;
          this.textareaNovel.nativeElement.setSelectionRange(firstIndex,lastIndex);
        }, 100);
      },
      e => console.error(e),
      () => console.info("completed")
    );
  }
```